# Set configurable products to In Stock while creating

Tags: magento2.3, configurable-product, stock-status

Currently when I am creating a new configurable product, it is by default set to out of stock, even though I have added quantity to each of the configurable products. To set the product as in stock I have goto each of the products and change the stock status.
Is there any way to set the configurable product as in stock while creating the product itself.
I am using Magento 2.3.3

Comment: are you using \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory to create a new paroduct ?

Comment: I am not sure, I am doing it through admin.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating like this.

```
// \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product

$product = $this->product->create();
//set data you want to set here
$product->setMetaTitle($name);
$product->setMetaKeyword($name);
$product->setMetaDescription($description);
$product->setPrice((int)$price);

$product->setStockData([
                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 1,
                    'manage_stock' => 1,
                    'is_in_stock' => 1,
                    'qty' => (int)$qty
                ]);
$product->getResource()->save($product);

$productId = $product->getEntityId();
```

Hope this will help you !!